# Resources for studying holography for someone with a long gap in physics

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education, ads-cft, holographic-principle

for the past 3 years I haven't been reading up on physics and I'd now like to get back into it by learning about holography. I have done courses on QFT and String theory but some concepts I've forgotten.

I am going to be a part of a research project on holography, so I need to learn at a level to at least understand the prominent papers on it.

What resources would you suggest?

I have bought Kirtsis' book on String theory but it doesn't seem to emphasize the physical intuition even though the mathematical level seems appropriate for one wanting to get to a research level with regards to holography. I've also found the following course from MIT (with video lectures) but from a first glance it doesn't seem to offer a lot of mathematical depth (which makes sense since String theory is not in its list of prerequisites):
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/

Answer (score 1):

Holography in itself is a very broad term. So assuming you would be somewhat "mainstream", there are many good works. See https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0203101 on the holographic principle by Bousso. On emergence of bulk in AdS/CFT, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01040. An invaluable resource is the lecture notes by Hartmann http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/gravity-lectures.pdf, which is a nice review on several aspects in quantum gravity, including the black hole information problem, AdS/CFT, aspects of the information problem in AdS, correlators, and a very good discussion on holographic entanglement entropy. See also gauge/gravity duality by Horowitz and Polchinski https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0602037v3 for a nice idea of this. Holography in general is a very large field, so assuming you are going to be interested in something like AdS/CFT particularly, there are *many* works you have to keep in mind. If your research falls into something like I am interested in (having to do with things like bulk reconstruction, JLMS and other things), it is best to read the papers themselves. Many of these kinds of things involve things like Tomita-Takesaki modular theory and a good understanding of operator algebras, so keep in mind that works in holography (not limited to AdS/CFT but in general any holographic description) are not very straightforward. In AdS/CFT itself, there are many works, like Ryu-Takayanagi, Hubeny-Rangamani-Takayanagi (arguably the most important works in the field), Faulkner-Lewkowycz-Maldacena, Jafferis-Lewkowycz-Maldacena-Suh, Engelhardt-Wall, Ceyhan-Faulkner, Bousso et al works, ...  and many other important works -- happy reading!